# Classify the group G

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

Consider $G$,  all $3\times 3$ matrices where all elements are in $\mathbb Z_2 .\;$ $G$ is a non-abelian group.

What steps do I go about to classify this group?

This means I have to find another group that it is isomorphic to,  correct?

$$G =\begin{pmatrix} 1&a&b\\0&1&c\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Do you specifically want the group of _upper triangluar_ matrices? Or the full group of invertible matrices?

Comment: It's a non-abelian group of order $8$, and there is exactly one "named" group with those properties.

Comment: How did you find the order?

Comment: Two choices for each of a, b, c:  $2\times 2 \times 2 = 8$.

Comment: No, you don't.  We are guaranteed, given all non-zero values on the diagonal, that these eight matrices are invertable. The only difference between matrices in $G$ are which values $a, b, c$ are, given that $a, b, c \in\{0, 1\}$.  There are eight distinct assignments of values to each of the three.

Answer (score 2):

A good first step is to count the elements in $G$. As the entries are in $\mathbb{F}_2$, it follows that $|G|=2\cdot2\cdot2$ where we have a binary choice for each $a,b,c$.

So the group has $8$ elements, which leaves us with only $5$ choices for what $G$ could be isomorphic to. But you know $G$ is not abelian, so what would be a good guess?

Comment: I would consider Q8 or D4 (in class we state |D4| = 4*2, some people call this D8, but we call it D4 for some reason). So then we would have to look at the order of specific elements next

Comment: @Clover3 Sounds like a good idea to me. As a side note, both conventions for the Dihedral Groups are common.